# Allowing redundant null-pointer check at trust boundary

Tags: c, clang, static-analysis

I was recently looking at some code where clang generated warnings due to `-Wtautological-pointer-compare`.

The code could be simplified to something like:

```
void foo(const char*s) __attribute__((nonnull)) {
   if (s) { /* Test added just in case*/
      if (s[0]=='a') s[0]='b'; /* Dummy code using the pointer */
   }
}
```

Obviously if we trust the attributes then `s` cannot be null and the warning is redundant. However, to me it seems best to handle the null-case in function (since we cannot trust that the calling code is compiled with these warnings, or that people read warnings) - while still detecting other null-pointer issues in the code.

Thus disabling this warning (using a pragma for the entire function) seems sub-optimal.

In Visual Studio with SAL it seems you can use `_In_ _Pre_defensive_` to handle 
this case.

> In that case, `_In_ _Pre_defensive_` is preferred at a trust
>   boundary to indicate that although a caller will get an error if it
>   attempts to pass NULL, the function body will be analyzed as if the
>   parameter might be NULL, and any attempts to de-reference the pointer
>   without first checking it for NULL will be flagged.

Is something similar possible with clang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the issue is worse than just seeing an unwanted warning. Since the function has that attribute, the compiler will remove the `if` as if you wrote:

```
if (true)
```

because you promised that the pointer will not be `NULL`. So your null check has no effect. See:

https://godbolt.org/z/l8w4x1

```
int func(void* ptr) __attribute__((nonnull))
{
    if (ptr)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

It unconditionally returns 1:

```
mov eax, 1
ret
```

So you should take that warning seriously.

I don't know of any workaround for this other than compiling with `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` to prevent null pointer checks from being optimized out, and `-Wno-tautological-pointer-compare` to silence the warning. You don't want to use these flags globally, obviously. So you should consolidate functions with this attribute into their own source file and use these flags only when compiling that file.

Comment: Hmm... That indicates a severe miscommunication among compiler writers. Some describe it as "This function attribute specifies function parameters that are not supposed to be null pointers. This enables the compiler to generate a warning on encountering such a parameter." However, recent versions of clang says "must not be a null-pointer" and calling it with a null-pointer is UB.

Comment: @HansOlsson Yes, it seems like a documentation issue. GCC clearly states: "*Unless disabled by the -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks option the compiler may also perform optimizations based on the knowledge that certain function arguments cannot be null.*" But clang doesn't mention that and says it's UB. But when clang added support for `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks`, they made the behavior be like GCC: https://reviews.llvm.org/D47894. So it seems it's not UB as long as you use `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` for the functions in question.